# Spring MVC : HTTP Status 404 - /SimpleMVC/WEB_INF/HelloPage.jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am trying to develop a simple Spring MVC web app. 
    I am getting  **HTTP Status 404 - /SimpleMVC/WEB_INF/HelloPage.jsp 
    The requested resource is not available.**
I am new to Spring MVC .

This is my web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>SimpleMVC</display-name>
      <servlet>
      <servlet-name>front-controller</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>front-controller</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

This is my front-controller.

```
    <bean name="/welcome.html" class="controller.HelloController"></bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB_INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix"> <value>.jsp</value></property>
    </bean>
```

This is my Controller :

```
 package controller;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;



    public class HelloController extends AbstractController {

        @Override
        protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
            ModelAndView giveBackMessage = new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
            giveBackMessage.addObject("welcomeMessage","This is the response got from Controller");
            return giveBackMessage;
        }




    }
This is my Response JSP:


 <html>
    <body>
    <h1>$(welcomeMessage)</h1></body>
    </html>



I dont know where i am missing. Please help me where i am going wrong
```

Comment: Missed adding one more bean in front-controller-servlet.xml             <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"></bean>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mentioned wrong prefix in viewResolver.

`<property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB_INF/</value>`

Correct one should be

`<property name="prefix"> <value>/WEB-INF/</value>`

Also
`<h1>$(welcomeMessage)</h1></body>`

should be

`<h1>${welcomeMessage}</h1></body>`

Comment: Thank you Vijendra. however it dint fix the issue. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Any specific reason to extend AbstractController. I missed this part from your code. I believe it is not required. Also not HandlerMapping required. remove these and try.

Comment: Hey Thank you Vijendra. The problem was WEB_INF. As you said it should be WEB-INF. It solved the problem.

Comment: Hey Can you please accept this answer if it solved your problem? Just below the down arrow you will see the tick mark to accept.